Function of VALUE inside WEEKDAY
I'd like to know what this is doing:
     IF(WEEKDAY(VALUE(D159)=1), D159-3)

I understand what the VALUE and WEEKDAY functions do, separately in basic terms, but am confused by the above value function being made equal to 1 inside the WEEKDAY function. Is it forcing a FAIL?
The context in which this is being used is for when Monday is a holiday, then go back 3 days to the Friday date. The data in the D column are dates. We want the result to be a Friday if Monday is a holiday, but I just don't understand the syntax.

I have looked up the function of both VALUE and WEEKDAY

I have tested the if statement with different date values to see what the result is

I've tried to find online instances where this specific usage was used


Thanks,
Cheryl

I suspect the formula you've postedhas a misplaced parenthesis - I think it should be =IF( WEEKDAY( VALUE( D159 ) ) = 1, D159 - 3) - i.e. if D159 contains an Excel datevalue for a Sunday, then get the preceding Thursday's datevalue - would you agree?

Go through your formula step by step: 1.) e.g. today is 8/17/2024, 2.) the value of today is 45521, 3.) the result of =45521=1 (or for any reasonable date) is equal to FALSE: Busted!, 4.) the result of =WEEKDAY(FALSE) or =WEEKDAY(0) is 7 (Saturday). BTW, the value of 1/1/1900 is 1 while the value of 1/0/1900 is 0. How do the holidays fit into the story? If you want Monday to be the first day of the week and you want to replace it with the previous Friday, you could simplify with =IF(WEEKDAY(D159,2)=1,D159-3,D159). There is no need for the VALUE function here.

the formula if TRUE will do D159-3 , what it should do if FALSE.
